# Arrays in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can I use arrays in jQuery?

I only want to use numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in a textbox, but how can I set the array and retrieve it?

e.g. if I'm using `d.charAt(1) == "1"` it is only 1 number, I want to be able to check for 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 to use the same index. I know I can use `||`, but what if I were trying to check for 100 numbers?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: My friend, is your keyboard broken?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict input in a textbox to numbers only I've used [jquery.numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

You can use this with textareas also!

Comment: If you need that user can only enter numbers (1,2,3,..) then this plugin works fine. You need to set css-class to '.numeric' (or some other to identify text-boxes) on textboxes you want to use it with. If you have specific need for `array` please elaborate on it a little bit more. I am not able to get what you mean by this.

Comment: em i gve u eg : user input 03-**** ,at index 0 is 0 ,and index 1 is 3... i want when user input 03 and the symbol "-" automtc show .. i use charAt(1) == "3" but i wnt user input 04 or 05 or 06 ..3,4,5 n 6 only use at index 1 .. sry if my explnation u nt undrstnd :) ..

Answer (score 0):

use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)